# Adding objects to a list in angular 2 typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am facing a problem to push data in a list here is my code.

```
labelListSelected: Label[];

onChange(object,flag){
   if(flag==false){      
           this.labelListSelected.push(object);
   }
   console.log(this.labelListSelected);
     //   console.log(object.Id+" : "+flag);
}
```

Comment: What is actually your problem? ;-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/WV8jX/702/...try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess its null pointer, change to:

labelListSelected: Label[] = [];

Comment: now can you tell me how to remove an element(object) from that array

Comment: array.splice(index, remove_count)

Comment: i want to remove specific element. how can i achieve

Comment: use array.indexOf to get item index